# How to read SIM Carrier name programmatically in iOS using Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift4.2

Before going in-depth, let me tell you all that - Yes, I've gone through all possible solutions provided on Stack-Overflow.

**Problem Statement :** I'm not able to read 'CarrierName' of my available SIM using iPhone

**What did I tried :** I've tried two different solutions, but I'm unable to read CarrierName.

**Solution 1 :** When I tried this solution I've received only **"Carrier"** as output, instead of CarrierName.

**Solution 1 :**

```
//--------------- CodeBase : Solution1 -----------------

let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let carrier = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.first?.value

  if let carrierName = carrier?.carrierName {
          cell.textLabel?.text = carrierName
    }
    else{
           cell.textLabel?.text = "No Data"
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output :** Carrier

**Solution 2 :** When I tried this solution I've received **"iPhone X"** as output, instead of CarrierName.

**Solution 2 :**

```
//--------------- CodeBase : Solution2 -----------------

let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let carrier = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.first?.value

        if var carrierName = carrier?.carrierName {
                
                if carrierName.contains("Carrier"){
                    carrierName = self.getCarrierName() ?? "No Data"
                }
                else{
                    cell.textLabel?.text = carrierName
                }
            }
            else{
                
               cell.textLabel?.text = "No Data"
            }
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

**Func : getCarrierName()**

```
//--------------- CodeBase : Part of Solution2 -----------------

func getCarrierName() -> String? {
        
        var carrierName: String?
        
        let typeName: (Any) -> String = { String(describing: type(of: $0)) }
        
        let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "_statusBar") as! UIView
        
        for statusBarForegroundView in statusBar.subviews {
            if typeName(statusBarForegroundView) == "UIStatusBarForegroundView" {
                for statusBarItem in statusBarForegroundView.subviews {
                    if typeName(statusBarItem) == "UIStatusBarServiceItemView" {
                        carrierName = (statusBarItem.value(forKey: "_serviceString") as! String)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return carrierName
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output :** iPhone X i.e. It returns ModelName instead of CarrierName

Can someone, please help me to get - CarrierName.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (`Xcode 11.4, Swift 5.2, iPhone 8, iOS 13.3.1`), I can get the proper carrier name.

Code snippet:

```
import CoreTelephony

if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    if let providers = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders {
        providers.forEach { (key, value) in
            print("key: \(key), carrier: \(value.carrierName ?? "nil")")
        }
    }
} else {
    let provider = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().subscriberCellularProvider
    print("carrier: \(provider?.carrierName ?? "nil")")
}
```

The result in console is:

```
key: 0000000100000001, carrier: 中国电信
```

Comment: Thanks @0xa6a, will try it.

Comment: Hi @0xa6a, I didn't get CarrierName, instead of this it return output as "Carrier"

Comment: @Ashish That's weird. In fact I've tried on another phone (iPhone 6, iOS 12.4.5) and it still returned the proper carrier name. Did you just try with my code snipped, or some other?

Comment: I suggest you paste all your related code in a well formatted way.

Comment: Yup...tried as you mentioned. And I've posted my all code-base properly.

Comment: Do we need to add some permissions in info file?

Comment: I've tried in a brand-new demo project without any permission manifest in `info.plist`, and still get the proper carrier name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212349/discussion-between-0xa6a-and-ashish).